# If statements using OR and Matrix fields

Tags: matrix, conditionals

I have a Matrix field that includes three options. The aim is to output a `<select>` element if one or more of these options is selected. (These fields are Pixel & Tonic Field Pack checkboxes.)

This syntax used to work:

```
{if "{gold}" OR "{silver}" OR "{wood}"}
    <input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Frame Type">
    <select name="os0">
        {if gold}<option value="Gold">Gold Frame</option>{/if}
        {if silver}<option value="Silver">Silver Frame</option>{/if}
        {if wood}<option value="Rosewood">Rosewood Frame</option>{/if}
    </select>
{/if}
```

Now that I've upgraded to EE 2.8.1 (from a much earlier version—E 2.2) the code isn't working and I'm getting the following error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: User Warning
Message: Invalid EE Conditional Variable: {if ""y"}
Filename: libraries/Functions.php
Line Number: 2640
```

I've tried all sorts of syntax combinations, such as removing the quotes and braces etc. The only solution I could find was pretty inefficient:

```
{if gold}
    <input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Frame Type">
    <select name="os0">
        {if gold}<option value="Gold">Gold Frame</option>{/if}
        {if silver}<option value="Silver">Silver Frame</option>{/if}
        {if wood}<option value="Rosewood">Rosewood Frame</option>{/if}
    </select>
{if:elseif silver}
    <input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Frame Type">
    <select name="os0">
        {if gold}<option value="Gold">Gold Frame</option>{/if}
        {if silver}<option value="Silver">Silver Frame</option>{/if}
        {if wood}<option value="Rosewood">Rosewood Frame</option>{/if}
    </select>
{if:elseif wood}
    <input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Frame Type">
    <select name="os0">
        {if gold}<option value="Gold">Gold Frame</option>{/if}
        {if silver}<option value="Silver">Silver Frame</option>{/if}
        {if wood}<option value="Rosewood">Rosewood Frame</option>{/if}
    </select>
{if:else}&nbsp;
{/if}
```

At least it works, but it's pretty darned ugly and inefficient. I had to put that ugly `if:else` at the end, too, as each of the options is optional, so to speak.

Can anyone suggest a better way to construct this?

Comment: Whilst not on topic, use 2.7 - they changed a lot in 2.8 & these little modules break.

Comment: Hi Stuart. How easy/hard is it to go back a version? Seems like a losing battle to me to stay on older versions. Eventually you have to face the music, no?

Comment: If you have database backups and files its quite straight forward. You will have to manually delete/import the db & replace files - no official way to revert. I never update ro latest release and 2.8 was a major release which affected alot of addons.

Comment: Thanks Stuart. Is there a way to acquire older versions of EE? Only the latest is offered on the EE site, so far as I'm aware.

Comment: Just fling EllisLab an email asking for 2.7.3 & they'll sling you a copy - will need serial.

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing what you are testing i'm assuming you are testing if the field has a value in it. So I would do this.

```
{if "{gold}" != "" || "{silver}" != "" || "{wood}" != ""}
      <input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Frame Type">
      <select name="os0">
          {if gold}<option value="Gold">Gold Frame</option>{/if}
          {if silver}<option value="Silver">Silver Frame</option>{/if}
          {if wood}<option value="Rosewood">Rosewood Frame</option>{/if}
       </select>
{/if}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @mattsidjohn. Nice suggestion, although it still throws an error for me. I've updated the post to show the error, and also sorry for not clarifying that these are P&T checkbox options.

Comment: I'm assuming you have, but did you try Matt's suggestions, but without the quotes, and without both quotes and braces as well?

Comment: You have ""y" in your if statement thats why its throwing the error. You can only have 2 quotes "y".